# Loading image loads in FireFox but not in IE9

Tags: javascript, image, firefox, tree, internet-explorer-9

I am facing an issue with the image loading. It loads properly on FireFox but fails to load in IE9. It is basically a progress status image on expanding a tree block.
Kindly help on how to deal with such an issue.

---

```
<div id='progressdiv' style='background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
border: 1px solid #CAD7D9;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 25px #CCCCCC;
display: none;
left: 50%;
padding: 5px;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
z-index: 2000;'>
<img border="0" src="img/magnifyingGlass_0.gif"  />                        
</div>
```

---

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" width="670">
        <tr class=fixedHeader>
            <th height="<%=Constants.LIST_HEADER_HEIGHT - 2%>" width="15"
                class="recordHeader" align="center"><img border="0"
                style="cursor: pointer;" name="userimgAll" openall='false'
                onclick="openAllTreeBlocks(this, 'user')" src="img/plus.gif"
                height="9" /></th>
            </th></tr> 
</table>
```

---

```
function openAllTreeBlocks(image_, subname){
        $('#progressdiv').show();
        ....//lines of code
        $('#progressdiv').hide();
}
```

---

Comment: A whole paragraph of inline CSS ?! What does F12 Developer Tools tell?

Comment: could u add a JSFiddle?

Comment: There is no message in the F12 developer Tools. The whole page loads fine but strangely wont load the 'indicator' image on expanding the plus.gif in IE9

Comment: @Christian: How do you suggest I add it and where?

Comment: jsfiddle.net --> add an example of your problem and finally add the link in your post.

Comment: Unfortunately Jsfiddle.net is blocked at my place so not able to obtain result in it. 
It is basically a 'loading indicator' sort of an image which shows up when the function openAllTreeBlocks is called and hides once the request is complete. Is there any way out?

Comment: Did you try to clear the browser cache? Sometimes browser cache is evil.

Comment: Oh Yes, I did that in the first place! Dint work...

Comment: Could it be an issue with synchronous/ asynchronous Ajax calls ?
Currently, it is an asynchronou ajax call.

Comment: @Teemu : Need your input on this!

Comment: Its an Animated GIF file!!